# Swift SpriteKit static nodes rotating?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

https://github.com/lemubru/zombie
--link to xcode project

I create a floor in my game and add enemy soldiers as spritenodes, I also shoot spritenode bullets from a gun.

After about 1 min of playing the game the floor seems to start rotating and hits all my other nodes.

```
   floor.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2,size.height/2 - 130)
    floor.name = "floor" //add reference to the button.
    floor.zPosition = 1
    addChild(floor)

    floor.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: floor.texture, size: floor.size)
    floor.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    floor.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    floor.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    floor.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
```

Comment: Try turning on debug physics to see what the physics bodies look like when this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when your floor tile nodes are overlapping and another physics body is applying a force to them. Make sure your tiles are not overlapping and run some more tests.

On a side note, you should not have usesPreciseCollisionDetection for your floor as it produces additional overhead. Instead use it for faster moving nodes like bullets.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the floor tiles are definitely not overlapping.  I keep spawning enemies above the floor and also shoot bullets constantly at the floor to ricochet  into the enemy soldier nodes: Meaning alot of collisions onto the floor, is this just a bug?

Comment: @FrankduPlessis - The number of collisions should have no effect on a static tile moving. I suggest you double check if there really are no overlaps. If that's the case you can try locking the nodes into place using SKConstraint. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/index.html